# Script to monitor for programs that are calling home

Tags: security, networking

I have a friend's Windows machine I think may be compromised by some sort of capture and control program.  I want to be able to see all the IP addresses which the computer tries to perform a call home to.  I want to keep this extremely simple and not delve into a packet analyzer like Wireshark.  I just want to give her a program to install (with simple instructions)  that captures and logs all the IP addresses so she can email the list to me and I can review them.  Does anyone know of a program which can do this?

Comment: Why not try and fix it and get rid of spamware, malware and worst case a clean install?

Comment: I want to go fishing and I think this is my opportunity.  This is more about me having fun than really fixing the problem.  I'm tired of being tech support without any payback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be to write a batch script that periodically calls `netstat -a -b` and outputs the results to a text file

```
@echo off
:restart

rem Run netstat and append to logfile
netstat -a -b >> C:\logfile.txt 

rem Delay for 60 seconds
ping localhost -n 60 >nul

goto restart
```

By way of explanation:

`netstat` is a command line tool to report on network statistics.
The parameter `-a` will list all active connections (inbound and outbound)
The parameter `-b` (on Windows machines) will attempt to find the binary that the network activity is associated with.

`ping` is a command line tool to send an ICMP 'echo' packet over the network. Its only use here though is a quick way to add a delay to the script. It will ping localhost (the local machine) once a second for `-n` seconds, and redirect the output to null (as we are not interested in the results of the ping)

Comment: This is a link to more information on netstat: http://www.dti.ulaval.ca/webdav/site/sit/shared/Librairie/di/operations/informatique/windows/netstat_results.htm